# ParseQueryAdapter.setAutoLoad(true) does not refresh data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to auto load the data updated to the parse cloud. I am using ParseQueryAdapter to request updated data from Parse. I have also set commentsQueryAdapter.setAutoLoad(true) but it still doesn't refresh the data.

```
//Set up a customized query
    final ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseCommentsClass> factory =
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseCommentsClass>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseCommentsClass> create() {
                    ParseQuery<ParseCommentsClass> query = ParseCommentsClass.getQuery();
                    query.whereEqualTo("videoId", videoID);
                    query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    return query;
                }
            };

    // Set up the query adapter
    commentsQueryAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseCommentsClass>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(final ParseCommentsClass post, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.comments_layout, null);
            }
            ImageView ProfileView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
            TextView usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView commentsView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            String ProfileThumb = String.valueOf(post.getUserPic().getUrl());
            Picasso.with(SingleVideoView.this)
                    .load(ProfileThumb)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .resize(70,70)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(ProfileView);

            usernameView.setText(post.getUser());
            commentsView.setText(post.getComment());
            return view;
        }
    };

    // Disable pagination, we'll manage the query limit ourselves
   // commentsQueryAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(false);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.comments_list);
    listView.setAdapter(commentsQueryAdapter);
    commentsQueryAdapter.setAutoload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a method to achieve interval refresh from Parse Cloud.

```
private Timer autoUpdate;

     @Override
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            autoUpdate = new Timer();
            autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            commentsQueryAdapter.loadObjects();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 1500); // updates each 40 secs
        }
```